# Cucumber - How to run background only once

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Using Cucumber with Javascript and Selenium  I have the following Gherking file:

```
    Feature: Login

    Background:
        Given database is filled with these emails and passwords.
        | tobias@hotmail.com | 12345678 |
        | petecle@gmail.com  | 87654321 |

    Scenario Outline:
        Given I navigate to the landing page
        When I submit the login form with "<email>" and "<password>"
        Then I can see the welcome message

    Examples:
        | email              | password |
        | tobias@hotmail.com | 12345678 |
        | petecle@gmail.com  | 87654321 |
```

My issue is that the background runs twice. Is there a way I can run it only once?

Comment: Background runs per scenario, and as you are using a scenario outline with two data combinations, there will be two scenarios. And thus it will get executed two times. I don't think there is a way to stop this, but i think you can achie beforesuite using testng + cucmber

Comment: https://medium.com/agile-vision/cucumber-bdd-part-2-creating-a-sample-java-project-with-cucumber-testng-and-maven-127a1053c180

Comment: This is a nice article, you could use the @beforClass to fill database with details you want before running the featur

Comment: Why do you need to run it only once? Is there a problem that you are encountering?

Comment: Why do you want to run the same scenario with two emails? There's no evidence of some difference between those users. At least, it's not expressed in the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't run `Background` only once; It's meant to run before every scenario.

You'll need to use something other then `Background` if you only want to run those steps a single time.

For the purposes of answering the question for both you and for future readers, I'm going to make the assumption that your example is intentionally simplified.  If it isn't, I'm not quite sure why you'd be running this test with two examples but the same outcome.

As I see it, you have three options to run some functionality once only.

1. Use Gherkin 6's [Rule](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/?sbsearch=background#rule) functionality to separate these examples.  A `Background` section should only apply to the `Rule` it's embedded within.
2. Use a [Conditional](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#conditional-hooks) `Before` hook to populate your database with each entry before running the requisite step.
3. **This is my preferred option**: Remove this setup step from your features entirely.  IMO, examples should only contain information that is useful to the reader.  Your `Background` here appears to only be configuring the database.  That could be better done in setup code outside of Cucumber.

If your intention is to demonstrate to the user that these emails exist, then it would be clearer (IMO) if you set up your database outside of your code, then used a meaningful address.  Something like `a_user_email_that_exists@gmail.com`.